# Auto fix path when cding

Tags: shell, zsh, symlink, prompt

I have my home directory symlinked from a secondary drive. This has the unfortunate effect of sometimes resolving the symlink when I open terminals within the home directory. Hence my prompt goes from `~/somedir/` to `/Volumes/hdd/home/myuser/somedir/`

I've attempted to work around this in ZSH by using `chpwd_functions` as such:

```
function fix_home_path() {
  cd $HOME${PWD##$(cd $HOME; pwd -P)}
}
chpwd_functions=(${chpwd_functions[@]} "fix_home_path")
```

Evidently, it does not work because it causes a recursive loop.

What would be the correct solution?

Comment: As an aside, `chpwd_functions+=( fix_home_path )` is a clearer way to add a function to the hook.

Comment: ah! thankyou for that heads up @chepner, appreciated!

Comment: What is the need for your the symlink if I may ask?  I use [named directories](http://www.cs.elte.hu/zsh-manual/zsh_6.html#SEC27) for easy access, but that (obviously) lacks filesystem-related features as it's resolved only on ZSH level.

Comment: I find it easier to keep my home directory on a separate drive/partition. It aids in system rebuilds and lets me have things like a fast ssd and a large hdd. (although these days thats becoming less of a concern, so its largely the first point)

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions that work. Either

1. change the (official) location of your home to `/Volumes/hdd/home/myuser/somedir/`. At least on Linux, the change would happen inside `/etc/passwd` or somewhere like that, I'm not sure about OSX. That should make any well behaved application just use the correct directory as home and that includes Zsh.
2. You can also change the value of `$HOME` only at your shell. At `~/.zshenv` include

   `export HOME=/Volumes/hdd/home/myuser/somedir/`

Zsh will handle the prompt expansion correctly.

PS: should you wish to have fancy/weird expansions in your prompt you can define a function and have its return value included in the prompt. Example, a convoluted way to include the date in your prompt:

```
zsh -f # new zsh with default configuration values.
setopt PROMPT_SUBST
function myfunc() { date }
export PROMPT=' \"$(myfunc)\" %~ ' # single quotes, NOT double quotes!
```

That will call the function `myfunc` for every prompt display.